# How to fetch all the td values from a table?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a `table` from which I want to fetch all the `td` and pass their values using an AJAX call. Here is what I attempted, but details are coming through blank.

```js
$('#createData > tbody > tr').each(function(i) {
  var rowobj = new Object();
  var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
    Number = $tds.eq(0).val(),
    Quantity = $tds.eq(1).val(),
    date = $tds.eq(2).val(),
    Value = $tds.eq(3).val(),
    Containers = $tds.eq(4).val(),
    typeOfContainer = $tds.eq(5).val();

  rowobj.Number = Number;
  rowobj.Quantity = parseFloat(Quantity);
  rowobj.Date = eta;
  rowobj.alue = parseFloat(Value);
  rowobj.noofContainers = parseInt(Containers);
  rowobj.containerType = typeOfContainer;
  Details.push(rowobj);
});
```

Comment: Use `text()` or `html()`, not `val()`

Answer (score 2):

Hi i suggest you to use  `.text()` instead of `val()`

Comment: iused  this and solved $tds.eq(5).find("input").val();

Comment: how can i do this for a select tag ?

Comment: you can use val() for select field